# SQL Server SELECT datetime <= The Current Date & Time?

Tags: sql, datetime, select, compare

I have the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT MAX([TargetUnits]) AS MaxUnits
FROM [TaktBoards].[dbo].[TargetPlot]
WHERE [TargetDate] <= GETDATE()
```

My select statement is ignoring the time in the datetime field TargetDate it seems.  When I run the select I get 13.05085 no matter what time in the day I run it at.  The idea here is, for example, when I run the select at say 9:07am I should get a max TargetUnits of 8.389831 but I get 13.05085.  What am I doing wrong?

Andy

```
TargetUnits       TargetDate
0.9322034         2015-10-08 06:45:00.000
1.864407          2015-10-08 07:00:00.000
2.79661           2015-10-08 07:15:00.000
3.728814          2015-10-08 07:30:00.000
4.661017          2015-10-08 07:45:00.000
5.59322           2015-10-08 08:00:00.000
6.525424          2015-10-08 08:15:00.000
7.457627          2015-10-08 08:30:00.000
8.389831          2015-10-08 08:45:00.000
8.389831          2015-10-08 09:00:00.000
8.389831          2015-10-08 09:15:00.000
9.322034          2015-10-08 09:30:00.000
10.25424          2015-10-08 09:45:00.000
11.18644          2015-10-08 10:00:00.000
12.11864          2015-10-08 10:15:00.000
13.05085          2015-10-08 10:30:00.000
```

....

Comment: You know that today is `2015-10-09` and not `2015-10-08`? Just asking.

Comment: you are using `max` on targetunits field, which gives you `13.050585`. Why do you expect it to be `8.389831`?

Comment: OMG.. such a loser today.  Thanks fancyPants, that was it.  I've had my head too buried in code obviously.

Comment: @Andy I recommend you delete this question, now that you know the reason :-) (better yet, **don't delete** it)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - better to keep question here; such nice little oops'es make surfing SO a bit more funny :)

Comment: @Arvo Yes, might be :-) This reminds me of [**The best programming joke**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)